# How to load dojo into html file in order to call dojox.mobile functions?

Tags: eclipse, dojo

Ok so I'm fairly new to dojo and I'm trying to make a really simple sample mobile app.  I'm using eclipse to run the code which uses an android emulator to install/run the app.  The problem I'm having is that I keep getting Uncaught Reference Errors for either "require is not defined" or "dojo is not defined", causing my app to appear as plain text instead of formatted like an android app using dojox.mobile widgets.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,
minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>PhoneGap</title>

<!-- DOJO -->

<script src="/assets/www/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad:true">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/www/lib/dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/android/android.css" 
type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/www/cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>

<script>
require(["dojo"], function(dojo) {
    dojo.require("dojox/mobile")
    dojo.require("dojox/mobile/parser")
});
</script>
</head>

<!-- END DOJO -->



<body>
<!-- ACCIDENT TOOLKIT PAGE -->
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="accHelp" selected="true">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Accident</h1>
    <div class="text">If you are in an accident, you should first move to a safe 
    location. Below are some additional actions you can take:</div>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" 
            onclick="window.location='geo:0,0?q=police';">Call the Police</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            onclick="window.location='geo:0,0?q=towing';">Call for a Tow Truck</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Exchange Driver Info</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Record Accident Location</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" moveTo="accInfo" transition="slide"
            onClick="itemClicked();">Take Photos of Accident</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- EXCHANGE DRIVER INFO PAGE -->
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="accInfo">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Accident" moveTo="accHelp"
        onClick="console.log('Going back');">Driver</h1>
    <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory">Other Driver Info</h2>
</div>

<script>
function itemClicked() {
  console.log("itemClicked()");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anything appear wrong with the code itself?  Especially where I'm using the script scr... to point to the dojo.js and where I'm using require to call the dojo.mobile functions.  I was under the impression that as long as the src pointed to the right location in the package tree, it didn't much matter where I copied the file in.

I have tried using the Google CDN to call dojo.js, but the emulator throws errors when I do so, possibly because it doesn't utilize an internet connection?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing /assets/www/ from your local URLs

Comment: I changed the local URLs like you said so that they are now accurate, but the app still ends up looking the same.  Instead of using the dojo calls to make it format like an android app, it only appears as plain text on a white background.  Could this be because I'm using Android API 15?

Answer (score 0):

Your require statement looks like this:

```
require(["dojo"], function(dojo) {
    dojo.require("dojox/mobile")
    dojo.require("dojox/mobile/parser")
});
```

And it should look something like this:

```
require([
    "dojo/mobile",
    "dojo/mobile/parser"
],
function(mobile, parser) {
    // your code here;
});
```